# How to re-route package to Google Load Balance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've a question for google load balance, I've a VM in Google Compute Engine.
For now I'm under DDoS attack, I think I should use google load balance.
My vm will send a heartbeat to other public server, it will show my real vm IP.
Blue line is now staus, red line is my solution.
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My server will send a heartbeat to a public server, some attacker will see my real vm ip, I'll under DDoS attack. I think I should use Load Balance and re-route heartbeat to Load blance.